# My discord bot won't respond to my command

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

So I'm pretty new to javascript, trying to get a bot to work. I get no errors, but when I try to use the bot in the server it is added in, it won't respond. I tried putting a console input in between the `client.on` and the `if` statement to see if I got input into my console, but no luck.
This tells me the issue is there, but after hours of editing and searching the web I didn't find anything. Thanks for the help!

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const client = new Discord.Client({ intents: [8] })



client.on("ready", () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
})

client.on("message", Message => {

if (msg.content === "Test") msg.reply("Success")
})

client.login(process.env['TOKEN'])
```

Comment: You define the message object as `Message`, but proceed to try and use something called `msg`

Answer (score 1):

The reason your bot is not responding to your messages is first of all, likely caused by incorrect intents provided.

The intents `[8]` resolves to a single intent (`GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS`), which is why the `message` event is not executing. **Do not confuse intents with permissions**. You need to subscribe to the right [intents](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/gateway#list-of-intents):

```js
const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    "GUILD_MESSAGES"
  ]
});
```

Secondly, your `message` listener takes a `Message` parameter, but the body of it is using a `msg` variable. Ensure you use the correct variables in your code:

```js
// "message" is deprecated, "messageCreate" is preferred
client.on("messageCreate", (msg) => {
  if (msg.content === "Test") {
    msg.reply("Success");
  }
})
```

Comment: @JoshuaDeClerck `ADMIN` is not an intent, that is a permission. Do not confuse the two.

Comment: well, I fixed my issue, it's still on 8 and works fine now...

Comment: interesting. Just wondering, what did you do to fix it?

Comment: reverted to V12

Answer (score 1):

**See this Image**
Where did you define "msg". You have taken the argument as Message and then you are trying to use "msg" to get the content of it. You can replace "Message" to be msg then It may work
[image]

#2)
If this isn't working, you can check if you have other instances of the BOT running. This happened to me also!

Answer (score -2):

Already found the issue, Discord.js v13 does NOT support `content` anymore. This was supported up to V12.

Comment: [`Message.content`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=content) still exists in v13

Comment: I think you're getting confused with the message content intent Discord is restraining next year